# RAID10 software raid converted as RAID0

Tags: linux, centos7, software-raid, mdadm, parted

On one of the server, The RAID10 software raid volume had became RAID0 after one the disks in the RAID10 disk group failed. Also the converted RAID0 volume has become inactive.

How can we recover the RAID volume after replacing the failed disk.

Thank you very much for your support.

Screenshots:

[image: mdadm --details of the Volume]

[image: mdadm --examine of slice1]

[image: mdadm --examine of slice2]

[image: mdadm --examine of slice3]

[image: mdadm --examine of slice4]

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!  We'll need more information before we can help you.  Please post the output of `mdadm --detail` for the array, and the output of `mdadm --examine` for each drive in the array.

Comment: Thank you @mike Andrews fort your response, Actually I have MD volume with 4 slices, one of them was failed due to underlying disk faults. The RAID10 volume went into Inactive state and became RAID1. After replacing the failed disk created partitions back. Recreated the RAID10 volume with the same partition, then the RAID10 volume back online but i am unable to mount it.

Comment: Please see attached images.

Comment: What happens when you try to mount it? What are the error? Also post `dmesg` logs after trying to mount it & also `blkid /dev/md127` would be nice.

Comment: Output of these commands is naturally text, not image, so much better is to attach them as text code-blocks into the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "paritions"? You have a partitionable array? Which one is replaced disk?